# How to identify colour of an icon of presence

Tags: android-studio

I am new to espresso .My test scenario involves to check the colour of the icon during the presence.For example if person X in available there is small green icon next to his name, if he is busy icon change to red
I am not quit sure how I can test colour of the specific icon R.id.presence
I do understand I need to use drawable but not sure how

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this. Try to find the element(probably R.id.presence in your case) and then try to get the background color of the element. Now compare it with the expected color.

Sample code for a button where green as background color is being verified.

```
Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.my_button);
Drawable buttonBackground = btn.getBackground();

ColorDrawable btn_color = (ColorDrawable) btn.getBackground();

int color = btn_color.getColor();
if (color == R.color.green) {
    log("color is green");
}
```

Hope it helps :)